# Issue with JSONP

Tags: jquery, json, spring, jsonp

As a part of learning JSONP, I am making an ajax call as follows:

```
var jsonp_url = "http://localhost:8080/test/ad";
$.getJSON(jsonp_url, function(data) {
   $('#example-widget-container').html(data.html);
});
```

When I hit http://localhost:8080/test/ad, it returns:

```
? ( {'html': '<strong>Hello World!</strong>' } )
```

The Spring code returning this is:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "ad")
public void getAd(HttpServletResponse response){
    PrintWriter out = null;
    response.setContentType("text/javascript");
    try {
        out = response.getWriter();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    out.write("? ( {'html': '<strong>Hello World!</strong>' } )");
}
```

On execution, I am expecting **Hello World!** to be displayed within `<div id="example-widget-container"></div>`, but it's not, as the callback is not happening.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found many confused about JSONP with JSON. So I'm sharing the answer I found to be correct:

Java

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "ad")
public void getAd(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
   ServletOutputStream out;
   try {
      out = response.getOutputStream();
      response.setContentType("text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
      out.println(request.getParameter("callback")+" ( {'html': '<strong>Hello World!</strong>' } )");
      out.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Javascript

```
var jsonp_url = "http://localhost:8080/AppName/ad?callback=?";
$.getJSON(jsonp_url, function(data) {
   $('#example-widget-container').html(data.html);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

$.getJSON except proper JSON fomat and callme({'html': 'hello world' }) is not a json format

proper json format is
{'html': 'hello world' }

Comment: you quiet right so the getJSON would fail as its expecting JSON.

Comment: But this isn't about JSON, but JSONP. http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/

Comment: @James don't return anything. just print the result on your server script. so it should look like {'html': 'hello world' }. $.getJSON will do rest of remaining work.

Answer (score 1):

don't you just want to `return "{'html': 'hello world' }";` ?

Comment: I'm confused as well but he does set the contenttype to be Javascript

Comment: true, but the function in the callback just require's an json object, not a function with a json object as far is I can tell

Comment: No, returning just json would impose "Same Origin Policy". For more information: http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/

Answer (score 1):

If you're returning JSONP, don't get JSON... Try this

```
$.get("http://localhost:8080/test/ad", function(data) {
   alert(data.html);
}, 'jsonp');
```

Answer (score 0):

what is callme function doing? if you are returning "callme({'html': 'hello world' })"; then in your js code  alert will not alert "Hellow world".  You need to have data() i.e run the callme function

Comment: We can have a separate function named **callme** that will be called back. But using $.getJSON(url, callback), you would not need to have the function explicitly, I think.

Comment: Well your ajax call is not returning valid json. it is returning a string with the value of "callme({'html': 'hello world' })". In your spring code just change the return value to return "{'html': 'hello world' }";  and try it it should work. Are you using firefox with the firebug plugin. if not it might be worth getting to help see/debug what is being sent/returned from your server

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite easy using Spring 3.0 and above. In looking at the examples above however I am confused as to why you are treating the spring controller like a plain servlet and printing directly to the response stream. This should be avoided. You would be much better off using just returning a POJO representing your JSON array and let a JSON parser create the response.

The first task is to get Spring to return JSON. This is easily handled by adding @ResponseBody to your controller, telling the controller to serialize the POJO to the client. If you have Jackson in your classpath this will automatically be sent as JSON using the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter which is enabled with mvc:annotation-driven.

But JSON isn't enough. You want JSON-P, assuming that the client wants to use the JSON in a cross domain scenario. This can be accomplished in a number of different ways. You could implement a servlet filter using Spring's DelegatingFilterProxy. The filter can determine if JSON-P is being requested and you can tune the response accordingly.

So for my uses I prefer to extend the Spring 3.0 (+) MappingJacksonJsonView instead of a filter and check if the request param contained a key of "callback". If I want JSON or JSONP I can simply add a second servlet mapping to *.jsonp and send either JSON or JSONP based on the presence of the callback parameter.

Here is the code:

Put the following in your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ad", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelMap getAvailabilityModel(@RequestParam(required = false) String callback) {
    ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
    modelMap.addAttribute("html", "<strong>Hello World!</strong>");
    return modelMap;
}
```

Returning a ModelMap or even a ModelAndView allows me to do different things based on the servlet mapping.

Here is the custom view to handle the JSON-P extension (guts only, left out some overrides for brevity):

```
public class MappingJacksonJsonpView extends MappingJacksonJsonView {

@Override 
public void render(Map<String, ?> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

if("GET".equals(request.getMethod().toUpperCase())) {

    Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();

    if(params.containsKey("callback")) {
    String callbackName = params.get("callback")[0];
    response.getOutputStream().write(new String(callbackName + "(").getBytes());
    log.info("GETTER Found for a .jsonp method, callback name is : " + callbackName);
    super.render(model, request, response);
    response.getOutputStream().write(new String(");").getBytes());
    response.setContentType("application/javascript");
    }

    else {
    super.render(model, request, response);
    }
}

else {
    super.render(model, request, response);
}
  }
 }
```

If the request is mapped to *.jsonp and I see a request parameter with "callback" as a key I assume JSON-P and I wrap the JSON with the callback information right on top of the response stream. I will let the Jackson JSON processor handle the specifics of converting the POJO to proper JSON in all cases. In my controller I just return a POJO or a ModelMap; no messing around to write my own JSON in the response. Alternatively I could have used a model and view for the return type. This will allow for the proper handling of *.do vs *.json requests. Use Firebug to ensure that you are getting the proper media type in the response headers, application/json for JSON and application/javascript for JSON-P.

Here is the output for JSON-P, with a GET on    http://localhost:8080/jsonpex/ad.jsonp?callback=xyz (Note the wrapper with the xyz, for JQuery use ?)

```
xyz({"html":"<strong>Hello World!</strong>"});
```

If you leave off the Request Parameter it will simply return JSON:    http://localhost:8080/jsonpex/ad.jsonp

```
{"html":"<strong>Hello World!</strong>"}
```

Finally, make sure you wire up the new view correctly:

```
<!-- Add our new View to the Application Context -->
<beans:bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
    <beans:property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
    <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
        <beans:map>
            <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
            <beans:entry key="jsonp" value="application/javascript"/>
        </beans:map>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="defaultViews">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"/>
            <beans:bean class="com.yourpackagename.spring.web.servlet.view.jsonp.MappingJacksonJsonpView"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

A couple notes, I would avoid sending back all the extra HTML and minimize as much as I can, leaving the crux of work to be done on top of the data being returned. I did a lot of research and tried many approaches; this one above worked best for me. I suggest the following as alternatives and additional reading as they are what led me to this ultimate solution (I can't remember them all sadly or I would give more credit):

http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

and for a filter solution:

http://jpgmr.wordpress.com/2010/07/28/tutorial-implementing-a-servlet-filter-for-jsonp-callback-with-springs-delegatingfilterproxy/

Trip